# Failure running JavaFX 2.2 using Maven

Tags: maven, javafx-2

I use Zen's Maven plugin to develop my JavaFX 2.2 application using Maven. The following is the plug-in declaration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I fixed the `classpath` using the following command:

```
mvn com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:2.0:fix-classpath
```

and the fixing probably succeeded.

The compilation also worked but the process did not generate JavaFX main files such as the following:

```
/com/javafx/main/Main$1.class
/com/javafx/main/Main$2.class
/com/javafx/main/Main.class
/com/javafx/main/NoJavaFXFallback.class
```

Running the project produces the following exceptions:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:285)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 13 more
```

What is going wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The main jar doesn't contain these classes, but the plugin generates an additional jar in the "target/jfx" directory (or something like this). Use that jar to start your application.